# Tabela Associativa de Empresas e Usuários, Muitos para Muitos

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Estou iniciando meus estudos em ASP.NET e estou com uma certa dificuldade de fazer um vínculo entre 2 tabelas do tipo Muitos para Muitos.

Seguinte tenho 2 tabelas: Empresa e Usuário, de forma que uma empresa pode possuir vários usuários e ao mesmo tempo um usuário pode pertencer a várias empresas.

Dessa forma criei uma tabela intermediária com chave estrangeira para ambas.

EX:

```
[TB_EMPRESA] [PK] COD_EMP, NOME_EMP

[TB_USUARIO] [PK] COD_USU, NOME_USU

[TB_USUARIOEMPRESA] [FK]COD_EMP, [FK]COD_USU
```

Porém estou meio perdido de como montar o *controller* e a *view* para fazer a inserção dos dados.

Alguém conhece algum artigo ou documentação que possa me ajudar?

Estou usando ASP.NET MVC5 e Entity Framework 6.

Answer (score 0):

[Já respondi várias e várias vezes sobre como fazer associação N para N aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+associativa+%5Bentity-framework%5D). De qualquer forma, vou esmiuçar isso pra você melhor.

Há duas formas de definir associação N para N no Entity Framework: via *Fluent API*, que é uma forma mais engessada porque não permite uma maior configuração da tabela associatva, ou por mapeamento manual, que dá um pouco mais de trabalho mas é melhor.

Primeiro, defina um *Model* assim:

```
public class UsuarioEmpresa
{
    [Key]
    public int UsuarioEmpresaId { get; set }
    [Index("IUQ_UsuarioEmpresa_UsuarioId_EmpresaId", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_UsuarioEmpresa_UsuarioId_EmpresaId", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }

    // Você pode definir mais campos aqui

    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }    
    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
}
```

[`[Index]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.indexattribute(v=vs.113).aspx), introduzido nesta forma a partir do Entity Framework 6.1.0, garante a unicidade do registro associativo. Validações adicionais podem ser necessárias na aplicação para evitar erros estranhos de duplicidade de chave para o usuário.

Com isso, estou supondo que você tem outros dois *Models* na sua aplicação com alguma coisa assim:

```
public class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }

    // Outras propriedades aqui

    public virtual ICollection<UsuarioEmpresa> EmpresasUsuario {get; set;}
}

public class Empresa
{
    [Key]
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }

    // Outras propriedades aqui    

    public virtual ICollection<UsuarioEmpresa> EmpresaUsuarios {get; set;}
}
```

Feito isso, podemos escrever um *Controller* manual ou gerar um via [*Scaffolding*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+scaffolding):

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SeuProjeto.Models;

namespace SeuProjeto.Controllers
{
    public class UsuariosEmpresasController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: UsuariosEmpresas
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            var usuarioEmpresas = db.UsuarioEmpresas.Include(u => u.Empresa).Include(u => u.Usuario);
            return View(await usuarioEmpresas.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: UsuariosEmpresas/Details/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            UsuarioEmpresa usuarioEmpresa = await db.UsuarioEmpresas.FindAsync(id);
            if (usuarioEmpresa == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(usuarioEmpresa);
        }

        // GET: UsuariosEmpresas/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.EmpresaId = new SelectList(db.Empresas, "EmpresaId", "Nome");
            ViewBag.UsuarioId = new SelectList(db.Usuarios, "UsuarioId", "Nome");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: UsuariosEmpresas/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "UsuarioEmpresaId,UsuarioId,EmpresaId")] UsuarioEmpresa usuarioEmpresa)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.UsuarioEmpresas.Add(usuarioEmpresa);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.EmpresaId = new SelectList(db.Empresas, "EmpresaId", "Nome", usuarioEmpresa.EmpresaId);
            ViewBag.UsuarioId = new SelectList(db.Usuarios, "UsuarioId", "Nome", usuarioEmpresa.UsuarioId);
            return View(usuarioEmpresa);
        }

        // GET: UsuariosEmpresas/Edit/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            UsuarioEmpresa usuarioEmpresa = await db.UsuarioEmpresas.FindAsync(id);
            if (usuarioEmpresa == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.EmpresaId = new SelectList(db.Empresas, "EmpresaId", "Nome", usuarioEmpresa.EmpresaId);
            ViewBag.UsuarioId = new SelectList(db.Usuarios, "UsuarioId", "Nome", usuarioEmpresa.UsuarioId);
            return View(usuarioEmpresa);
        }

        // POST: UsuariosEmpresas/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "UsuarioEmpresaId,UsuarioId,EmpresaId")] UsuarioEmpresa usuarioEmpresa)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(usuarioEmpresa).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.EmpresaId = new SelectList(db.Empresas, "EmpresaId", "Nome", usuarioEmpresa.EmpresaId);
            ViewBag.UsuarioId = new SelectList(db.Usuarios, "UsuarioId", "Nome", usuarioEmpresa.UsuarioId);
            return View(usuarioEmpresa);
        }

        // GET: UsuariosEmpresas/Delete/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            UsuarioEmpresa usuarioEmpresa = await db.UsuarioEmpresas.FindAsync(id);
            if (usuarioEmpresa == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(usuarioEmpresa);
        }

        // POST: UsuariosEmpresas/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            UsuarioEmpresa usuarioEmpresa = await db.UsuarioEmpresas.FindAsync(id);
            db.UsuarioEmpresas.Remove(usuarioEmpresa);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

E *Views* (também por *Scaffolding*):

## `Create.cshtml`

```
@model SeuProjeto.Models.UsuarioEmpresa

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>UsuarioEmpresa</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UsuarioId, "UsuarioId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("UsuarioId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UsuarioId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpresaId, "EmpresaId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("EmpresaId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmpresaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

## `Delete.cshtml`

```
@model SeuProjeto.Models.UsuarioEmpresa

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}

<h2>Delete</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<div>
    <h4>UsuarioEmpresa</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Empresa.Nome)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Empresa.Nome)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Usuario.Nome)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Usuario.Nome)
        </dd>

    </dl>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

## `Details.cshtml`

```
@model SeuProjeto.Models.UsuarioEmpresa

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>UsuarioEmpresa</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Empresa.Nome)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Empresa.Nome)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Usuario.Nome)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Usuario.Nome)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.UsuarioEmpresaId }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

## `Edit.cshtml`

```
@model SeuProjeto.Models.UsuarioEmpresa

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>UsuarioEmpresa</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UsuarioEmpresaId)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UsuarioId, "UsuarioId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("UsuarioId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UsuarioId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpresaId, "EmpresaId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("EmpresaId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmpresaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

## `Index.cshtml`

```
@model IEnumerable<SeuProjeto.Models.UsuarioEmpresa>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Empresa.Nome)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Usuario.Nome)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Empresa.Nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Usuario.Nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.UsuarioEmpresaId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.UsuarioEmpresaId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.UsuarioEmpresaId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Tendo isso, é só modificar *Controller* e *Views* de modo a obter o comportamento desejado.